# Inserting into a sorted list respecting sorting and avoiding duplicates

Tags: python, list

I know the trick to append to a list, convert it to a set to eliminate duplicates, convert it back to a list and apply sorting.

I would like to avoid this post-processing (if an alternative approach is more efficient).

So I am wondering if there is a direct way to insert into a sorted list while always respecting sorting and avoiding duplicates. As an example, inserting 3 into [1, 2, 4] shall yield [1, 2, 3, 4], and inserting 3 into [1, 3, 4] shall yield [1, 3, 4].

Is there a function for lists or aby other specific data structure available?

Is this more efficient than the usual approach „append - eliminate duplicates - sort“?

The length of the resulting list is typically < 10, the attempts to insert < 100 (so most inserts will fail), the function is called ~ 10^6 times. The data to be inserted are integers, so comparison is cheap.

Comment: I think a few more details about your specific use case would be useful, but one option is to work with a `set` the entire time and only convert to a (sorted) `list` at the very end.  This would avoid lots of unnecessary `list` -> `set` -> `list` conversions.

Comment: Do you need the intermediate lists (like after 42 of 100 insert attempts) or only the final list?

Comment: Only the final result is needed.

Comment: Then why don't you just insert all into a set and sort once?

Comment: Is this „insert into set, convert to list, sort“ cheaper than the bisect-approach (of course I will do some profiling).

Comment: Likely much cheaper, yes.

Comment: And maybe it could be further sped up if we knew the bigger picture, i.e., if we knew more about the million calls.

Comment: What do you expect? Which information ist missing? The integers n to be inserted are small, typically 1 < n < 10 … Anyway, thanks for the feedback. I‘ll do the profiling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bisect.bisect_left` to find the insertion point, then check if the element at that point is not the element you want to insert before calling `list.insert` to add it.

Note that it is `O(log N)` to find the insertion point, but `O(N)` to insert into an arbitrary position.

```py
import bisect
l = [1,2,4]
x = 3
i = bisect.bisect_left(l, x)
if i >= len(l) or l[i] != x:
    l.insert(i, x)
print(l) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```